# What does "<plural noun> ... to be identified" exactly mean?

Tags: logic

Let's assume that I received several packages but don't know where some of those came from. In this case, is it correct to say that the origins of the packages are yet to be identified? I wonder if this sentence implies that I don't know the origins of all of them. If so, could you suggest a phrase?

Comment: It implies 'all'. Why not simply say 'of some of the packages' as you did in your first sentence?

Answer (score 0):

It may be correct but it is mostly used if you really are going to find out where they came from.

Like, for example: Someone sends a threatening message to me, I would definitely want to find out who send it. Then I may say to my friends, in real movie style, that "The sender of this message is yet to be identified."